# Hibernate mapping a UserType inside a Map

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dictionary, annotations

I have come across a problem where I cannot persist a `Map<UUID, Integer>` using Hibernate.  I'm not sure how to properly annotate this collection such that it may be properly mapped into our database.  We control the schema, so any way this will work will be fine.  Do i need to specify what UserType the key is in my Map somehow?  Do I need one?  I know the Type annotation is used for individual fields.  Perhaps not collections?  I am receiving the following exception on my call to `session.flush()`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID`

```
@ElementCollection
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
private Map<UUID, Boolean> orderCount = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
```

Comment: can it be that UUIDCharType is meant for Strings not UUID?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to write a `UserType` to handle `Map<UUID, Boolean>` .. This `UserType` should then use `org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType` to map the key column.

Comment: How can you specify a UserType for the key and value column separately using annotations?

Comment: I found out how:  `@MapKeyType(value=@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType"))` will do it.  Doing this makes it unnecessary to create a `UserType`.  Does anyone know how to set one for the Value? (Even though it is not necessary here for a Boolean)

Comment: @Ryan could you plz take a look at my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307329/hibernate-4-what-should-replace-deprecated-mapkey-to-map-a-map-collection-whi