# Hibernate 4 - What should replace deprecated @MapKey to map a Map collection while Key is a customized Hibernate UserType

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Considering the following two tables:

```
| User      | UserAttribute     |
|---------- |-------------------|
| userId(PK)| attributeId(PK)   |
| firstName | userId            |
| lastName  | name              |
| other     | locale            |
| active    | value             |
```

In original `hibernate-3.2.2`, the **one-to-many bidirectional** relationship works fine:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class UserHbm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id-generator")
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String other;

    @Column
    private boolean active = true;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKey(columns = { @Column(name = "name"), @Column(name = "locale") })
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Map<AttributeKeyHbm, UserAttributeHbm> attributes = null;

    //other methods, getter & setting, etc...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAttribute")
public class UserAttributeHbm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id-generator")
    @Column(name="attributeId")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private UserHbm user;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

    @Column
    private String value;

    // other methods...
}
```

---

```
public class AttributeKeyHbm implements UserType {

    protected static int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR };

    private String name;

    private Locale locale;

    public AttributeKeyHbm(String name, Locale locale) {
        this.name = name;
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    //other override methods, assemble, deepCopy & nullSafeGet, etc...
}
```

What makes `hibernate` migration from 3.2.2 to 4.3.11 difficult is the costumed UserType `AttributeKeyHbm` as a key of `attributes` in `UserHbm`

`AttributeKeyHbm` is a costumed UserType of Hibernate, containing two columns from `UserAttributeHbm`, `name` and `local` respectively.

Since hibernate annotation `@MapKey` is [deprecated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/MapKey.html), I've tried to use the following annotations one by one, to replace the original `@MapKey`:

```
@MapKeyType(value=@Type(type="com.xxx.xxx.AttributeKeyHbm"))
@MapKeyJoinColumns(value={ @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "name"),  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "locale")})
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "AttributeKeyHbm")
```

But it all ends up with this exceptions:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: collection index mapping has wrong number of columns: com.xxx.xxx.UserHbm.attributes type: com.xxx.xxx.AttributeKeyHbm
```

So my questions are:

- How to implement the same function in `UserHbm` with `hibernate-4.3.11`, given that `AttributeKeyHbm` couldn't be abandoned cause it's already used by other API heavily.
- As `AttributeKeyHbm` has two columns, is it correct or enough to implement interface `UserType` instead of `CompositeUserType`

Comment: Why don't you mark `AttributeKeyHbm` as `@Embeddable`? In that case you can add `@Column` to the attributes of the class.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke could you elaborate more, plz?

Comment: What is unclear? Did you read the [Hibernate documentation of Maps](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#d5e5430)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should replace MapKeyType(Hibernate) with MapKeyClass(JPA) or just remove it since Hibernate will auto detect.

And MapKeyJoinColumns/MapKeyJoinColumn will be skipped in this case, refer to the JPA document https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html I guess they're used for entity only.

The exception means key UserType's column number is not the same with the key column. 
I can't find @MapKeyColumns but I tried @MapKeyColumn(name="id") and make AttributeKeyHbm only has "id" and it works.
So all is to find the MapKeyColumns-like annotation.